# Active Filter Triggered from Cell Data

Tags: vba, excel

What I would like would be a filter that I can type an entry into a cell, then have the rest of the column filter. When this entry is cleared, the sheet should return to how it looked before I started typing. Currently, when I delete from that box, it clears all data on the worksheet.

What I am currently using is this code. Anyone know how to make this work cleanly?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   If (Intersect(Target, Range("G2")) Is Nothing) _
   Then
      Exit Sub
   End If
   Cells.AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="=" & Range("G2")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this code will remove the criteria if you have a blank value in `G2`.  I also added a check to make sure your `Target` is only one cell as right now your code would trigger if you modified a whole range that included `G2`.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Row <> 2 Then Exit Sub
    Dim LastCol As Long
    LastCol = Cells(4, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    If Target.Value = "" Then
        Range(Cells(4, 1), Cells(4, LastCol).AutoFilter Field:=Target.Column
    Else
        Range(Cells(4, 1), Cells(4, LastCol).AutoFilter Field:=Target.Column, Criteria1:="=" & Target.Value
    End If
End Sub
```

Updated code to work for any value changed in row 2.

Comment: Chismas007 one more question on a related note that will show my lack of knowledge here. Why can't I make this same private sub work on cell "F2?" Also thanks so much for you help on this first part!

Comment: Well, my mistake may go in one of two directions. I changed the target cell to "F2" and the fields to "6," then it told me it was an ambiguous name, which was a stupid mistake because I forgot to rename it. When I did rename it, it was not longer a "worksheet" object, but a "(General)" object. I cannot figure out how to change that... Then again, that might be a symptom and not the issue itself.

Comment: When you use `Cells.AutoFilter` you are selecting every cell on the sheet.  Perhaps you should define the range you want to filter?

Comment: I made it 'Range("G4:G5401").AutoFilter Field:=7' to specify the autofilter. This didn't change anything, is that what you meant?

Comment: Try "A4:G5401" To get the whole table. Field 7 refers to the 7th column in your filtered areas

Comment: What is wrong with these two sets of code? `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If (Intersect(Target, Range("G2")) Is Nothing) Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub 'Need to make sure you didn't change multiple cells.
    If Target.Value = "" Then
        Range("A4:Z5401").AutoFilter Field:=7
    Else
        Range("A4:Z5401").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="=" & Target.Value
    End If
End Sub`

Comment: `Private Sub Worksheet_Change1(ByVal Target As Range)
    If (Intersect(Target, Range("F2")) Is Nothing) Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub 'Need to make sure you didn't change multiple cells.
    If Target.Value = "" Then
        Range("A4:Z5401").AutoFilter Field:=6
    Else
        Range("A4:Z5401").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="=" & Target.Value
    End If
End Sub`

Comment: @Jacob I just updated my code to work for any value changed in row 2.  (Will affect that specific column)